# swift NSUserdefault item not being deleted

Tags: swift, dictionary, nsuserdefaults

I am learning how to work with NSUserDefault and have an app where the user can add/delete a tableviewcell and the left over ones will be saved into NSUserdefault. The adding part works fine but the deleting part is giving me some trouble  (it's not deleting)

I am wondering where in my code did I made a mistake that's causing this problem. Thank you for your help in advance

EDIT: I have tried setting defaults.set(self.exchange.currencyToGetExchangesDictionary.keys, forKey: "currencies") however, when I delete the row Xcode gave me an error related to heights iirc. I've tried tableview.reload() on deleted row too but as I saw on other questions we shouldnt be doing that.

```
 override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    var savedArray = defaults.object(forKey: "currencies")
    if  savedArray != nil {
        savedArray = Array(self.exchange.currencyToGetExchangesDictionary.keys)
        self.initialRetrievingAndSavingData()
    } else {
        self.exchange.currencyToGetExchanged = ["USD","EUR","GBP"]
        self.initialRetrievingAndSavingData()
    }
}
// Tableview Functions-----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
    return self.exchange.currencyToGetExchangesDictionary.count
}

func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
    let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "currencyExchangeCell", for: indexPath) as? CurrencyExchangeTableViewCell
    let sortedKeys = Array(self.exchange.currencyToGetExchangesDictionary.keys)
    let sortedValues = Array(self.exchange.currencyToGetExchangesDictionary.values)
    cell?.currencyLabel.text = sortedKeys[indexPath.row]
    cell?.exchangeValueLabel.text = sortedValues[indexPath.row]
    defaults.set(sortedKeys, forKey: "currencies")
    return cell!
}


func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) {
    let indexPath = tableView.indexPathForSelectedRow!
    let cell = tableView.cellForRow(at: indexPath) as? CurrencyExchangeTableViewCell
    valueToPass = Array(self.exchange.currencyToGetExchangesDictionary.keys)[indexPath.row]
    self.getPastData(currency: valueToPass)
}

func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, canEditRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> Bool {
    return true
}

func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, commit editingStyle: UITableViewCellEditingStyle, forRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) {
    if (editingStyle == .delete) {
        self.exchange.currencyToGetExchangesDictionary.removeValue(forKey: Array(self.exchange.currencyToGetExchangesDictionary.keys)[indexPath.row])
        print(self.exchange.currencyToGetExchangesDictionary)
        currencyExchangeListTableView.deleteRows(at: [indexPath], with: .automatic)
    }
}
```

My printed result was after deleting the USD cell:

```
["EUR": "8,771.5230", "GBP": "7,688.9664"]
```

However, when i open the app again it still has USD EUR GBP

Comment: Where's the code that stores the updated data in `UserDefaults` after you remove a value?

Comment: @rmaddy i tried in my UITableViewCellEditingStyle function with defaults.set(self.exchange.currencyToGetExchangesDictionary.keys forKey:"currencies") but xcode gave me an error when I delete the row (soemthing about heights iirc)

Comment: Update your question with what you actually tried and fully explain what issues you are having. All of that information needs to be in your question.

Comment: Not related but it's very expensive and inefficient to use a dictionary as data source and separate keys and values in each call of `cellForRowAt`.